# Table data click event issue

Tags: jquery, html

How to alert table data where corresponding table head id="0". I have a dynamic table here with many table heads. one table head id is 0. how can i make an alert when clicked on table data corresponding table head.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>heading1</th>
<th id="0">heading2</th>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>heading11</th>
<th id="1">heading12</th>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>
</table>

$("th#0 td").live('click',function(){
alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using? As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: what data you want to alert and the jQuery version used

Comment: __I have a dynamic table here__ can you be more specific?

Comment: i just want to alert "clicked" when clicked on table data corresponding table head id="0"

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid table structure to me…. You've 4 head ins and 6 columns… and both are in same `<tr>`...

Comment: don't start ids with a number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt it's okay with html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#0~td").on('click',function(){
alert("clicked");
```

});

Comment: this method is good.And i have one more doubt, if td have a span class ".event" then how to identify the click event of ".event"          $("#0~td .event").on('click',function(){
alert("clicked");  is this right?

Comment: Yes, You may use this.May i know what is the necessity for this scenario.

Comment: $("#0~td .event") but this method is not working. can u suggest another way

Comment: That method  worked for me please check this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d32z80xq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like most of the other answers assumes that `<th>` and `<td>` containing data are siblings (*Well it is, in the given HTML*)

The proper table structure should be like

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>heading1</th>
        <th id="0">heading2</th>
        <th>heading11</th>
        <th id="1">heading12</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
        <td>data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
        <td>data6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can do this:

```
var index= $("#0").index();
$("table").on("click", "tr td:nth-child("+(++index)+")", function () {
    alert("click");
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/tfhyz2hq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query I hope it solves your query,

```
var dataa=$("th#0").siblings('td');
dataa.on('click', function(){
alert("clicked");
});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnehudLe/2/)**